# Should my h1 be my logo or the next title in my page?

Tags: html

I've always struggled with this decision, and I wanted to know if there are any structural or semantic reasons for handling it properly:

So consider that most sites have a logo (lets just say in the top right and the first html tag in the dom after the body), I typically use an `h1` for this element, then hide the text for that object, as it's usually an image.

But then the situation arises where I'll have a real title on the page, in our case say it's "Products", should this then be an `h2`? or should it be an `h1`? I was taught that you shouldn't have more than one `h1` on the page, but it seems to be the most important as the `h1` will never change.

Are there any SEO considerations or other reasons that I'd want to handle this in a certain way? Any input would be appreciated.

---

To clarify, when I say I hide the text, I usually would make the logo the `background-image` in my CSS, then I typically hide the text with the ol' `text-indent:-99999px`. I always thought this was the best way to make google index it properly.

Comment: Good question. I also want to know. Some nice information found by following the links in the "Related" questions in the right-side column here at SO...

Comment: More appropriate on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com

Comment: What would you normally place in your hidden h1 tag?  Can you give an example of a sentence which you would use?

Comment: @VictorKilo, what I mean is it would probably be the companies name or something, `<h1 id='logo'><a href='/'>My Company</a></h1>`.

Comment: I think that is an improper use of an h1 tag as it is not really a header for the page as much as it is a header for the site.  If it only says "My Company" on every page of your site, it's less likely that google will return relative pages.  The purpose of an h1 is to display the header for that specific page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to begin this by saying that I am no expert on this matter, this is only what I have been told by a number of sources.

I believe that the h1 tag should only be used for titles.  The reason being that they are a great SEO tool.  The h1 is a high ranking element in terms of the relevance of a page.

Placing an h1 around an image does nothing for your page, unless as you say, you place some descriptive text in it.  The problem with placing hidden text inside an h1 tag is that the Google bots are smarter than that.  They will either omit the tag entirely or place you on the blacklist (usually more than one instance needs to occur for this, but generally it's a bad idea to try and elevate your search rankings with hidden elements, meta tags excluded).

So, place your "products" heading in an h1.  On any additional pages which don't have titles, I would place a descriptive sentence from the page inside of an h1, and style it to match the surrounding text.  This will ensure that the bots know that the words within the tag are relavent to the page.

### Edit: for OP Edit

Regardless of whether you use `display:none` or `left-margin:-99999px`, it's still not a good idea.  That is a common way to hide text or elements, and I'm sure that it's not new to google ;)

Comment: I doubt that putting your logo with `alt` text in an `h1` would get your site placed on a blacklist. Your last suggestion about placing a descriptive sentence in an `h1` and restyling is kind of shady though. Use `h1`s for their semantic purpose. Other than these two objections, I think this is a fairly solid answer worth listening to.

Comment: Your first sentence is correct, however, the OP mentioned that he usually has hidden text inside of that h1 as well, which is what I was getting at.  The alternate h1 within a paragraph should only be used if no title exists, although I admit it is not very practical.  Thanks for your feedback :)

Comment: Ahh, must have skipped over the thing in the question about hidden text.